# Live styling part of text on list items to match user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

A Meteor client code receives a live input from user as being typed into an input box via the template `keyup` event.

On the page there is list items with text in each.  I need to apply a style to the part of the text in any of the list items which matches what the user is typing.
My attempt is not applying any styling at all.

How can it be done? Thanks

```
'keyup .check-filter': function(event) {
  showMatches(event.target.value);
}

showMatches: (userInput) => {
  if (userInput.length > 3) {
     //this is not doing the job for me.
    $('li').html($('li').html().replace('/' + userInput + '/gi', '<span class="myCSS">' + $1 + '< /span>')); 
  }
}
```

Comment: @LGSon could you please supply an input box for testing? thx

Comment: Will update soon with that

Comment: @LGSon Please use different strings in each of the list items. The string must remain as is but the user input needs to be styled. thx

Comment: @LGSon please include more than one list item, as each list item must retain its original text.

Comment: @LGSon I tried the loop as suggested in your answer but inside the loop this gives " Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" `$(this).html($(this).html().replace(re`. So I am not sure how to fix my loop. thx

Comment: @LGSon How would you wire this answer to Meteor client event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Updated*

For variables you need to use `RegExp`, also your function will add a `span` around every character group, which will make it fail when replace from the fifth letter, so you need to clear that part as well, not mentioned when deleting characters.

```js
// global, app specific, variables
var myApp = {
  userInput : {
    firstTime : true,
    lastValue : ""
  }
};

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function(e) {  
  var userInput = e.target.value;
  
  if (userInput.length > 3 || !myApp.userInput.firstTime) {
    if (!myApp.userInput.firstTime) {
      var re = new RegExp('<span class="myCSS">' + 
                          myApp.userInput.lastValue + 
                          '</span>','gi');

      $( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
        $( this ).html($( this ).html().replace(re, myApp.userInput.lastValue));
      });

    }

    myApp.userInput.firstTime = false;
    var re = new RegExp(userInput,'gi');    

    $( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
      $( this ).html($( this ).html().replace(re, '<span class="myCSS">' + userInput + '</span>'));      
    });

  }  
  myApp.userInput.lastValue = userInput;
  
})
```

```css
.myCSS {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Hello there, there is 2 or more word duplicates in  here</li>
  <li>This has 2 or more words as well, but is a completely different sentence</li>
</ul>

Test input: <input type="text"/>
```